# Replace date in string with another format of date

Tags: c#

I have a string

```
Subject: Trip Ticket\r\nDate: Sun, 18 May 2014 0:59:56 -0400\r\nImportance: 
Normal\r\nX-Mailer: Symposium Technologies Inc.
```

I want to replace the date like `Sun, 18 May 2014 0:59:56 -0400` with date like `27 May 14 16:28:00 UT`. where date is not static and can have any date. I do it using index but i think its not proper way because `0:59:56` may be 10:59:56 in future and it will start giving error then. Can any body know how to do it accurately.

Comment: The date seems always to be at the beginning of a line, does this rule always apply? Then you could replace theat line.

Comment: yes this always apply, it start with line and end with line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Just break the problem into smaller pieces:

1. Extract the date (string) out of the complete string, for example, by using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) twice: first on the line separator, then on the `:`.
2. Convert the date string into a `DateTime` using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx).
3. Convert the `DateTime` into the desired format using [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring.aspx).
4. Re-insert the formatted date into the string.

Note, however, that your text *looks like an e-mail* and that the `Date:` header in e-mails *must* have this format (see [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), section 3.3).

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
myDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r")
// It Displays :  Thu, 09 Apr 2014 11:45:09 GMT
```

OR :

```
myDate.ToString("m", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ms-MY"))
// Displays 09 April
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Format()

```
     var str =  string.Format(
                "Subject: Trip Ticket\r\nDate: {0}\r\nImportance: Normal\r\nX-Mailer: Symposium Technologies Inc.",
                yourDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

The date seems always to be at the beginning of a line, does this rule always apply?

> yes this always apply, it start with line and end with line

Then you can replace the line. For example with this:

```
string newDate = "27 May 14 16:28:00 UT";
string text = "Subject: Trip Ticket\r\nDate: Sun, 18 May 2014 0:59:56 -0400\r\nImportance: Normal\r\nX-Mailer: Symposium Technologies Inc.";
var newLines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(l => new { Line = l, DateIndex = l.IndexOf("Date:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) })
    .Select(x => x.DateIndex == -1 ? x.Line : x.Line.Substring(0, x.DateIndex) 
                                           + string.Format("Date: {0}", newDate));
text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newLines);
```